# ASP.NET Core MVC default routing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to change my default route template:

- {controller=Home}/{action=**About**}/{id?}

But when I start my project (without any url path - just: http://localhost:49406/) it always loads the Index instead of the About. I have no other routes and I don't use attribute routing at all.

I also tried to change the default controller:

- {controller=**Main**}/{action=Index}/{id?}

It loads the HomeController's Index instead of the MainController's Index.

Is it a bug or I forgot something?

Comment: Please share the actual source code

Comment: Is just the default ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) > Web Application project within Visual Studio 2017 Community. I didn't change anything except the route template in the Startup.cs. Which part of this large project template should I share?

Comment: Yes, can you please share route template code block from Startup and MainController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any attribute routing at all the problem should come from your `Startup.cs` file.

Make sure that you are calling `app.UseMvc()`only and not `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` in `Configure` method.

Comment: There was an app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() line far above the the app.UseMvc() part. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help you.